# How to add arrows with -webkit-scrollbar-button

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, arrows

I have a custom scrollbar. Since I did that, the arrows of the scrollbar are not shown anymore.

```
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: ##00a7e0;
  }

  .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
  }

  .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    ????;
  }
```

What do I have to add in .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button that my arrows are shown again?

Comment: Similar --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761611/adding-arrows-to-scrollbar

Comment: @ovokuro I've seen this post too, but is it really the only solution? Can you only add the arrows by an image?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(Super late to the party, but still)

You can style scrollbar buttons using ::-webkit-scrollbar-button selector (see [this blog post](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) for a full breakdown on the webkit scrollbar pseudo selectors), but getting them to show arrows is much trickier, and most people seem to either use background images or skip buttons altogether.

Here's a solution using CSS triangles for arrows:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229219/1202275

and another one (based on the one above, vertical scrollbar only but the idea is the same):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
  border: 5px solid white;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0.05em solid #eeeeee;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
/* Buttons */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 13px;
  width: 16px;
}
/* Up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
}
/* Down */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-color: #555555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
  border-color: #777777 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

(https://codepen.io/DarthVeyda/pen/eLLbXa)

Comment: It looks like `-webkit-scrollbar-button` no longer works? I'm on a Mac and it's not showing at least

Answer (score 20):

A newer version and better is this: [How do I switch to Chromes dark scrollbar like GitHub does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940522/how-do-i-switch-to-chromes-dark-scrollbar-like-github-does)

---

here is complete scrollbar with buttons with dark mode:

https://codepen.io/patrikx3/pen/ZEBQQyV

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

/* Buttons */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);

    display: block;
    background-size: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    height: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    background-position: center 4px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:active {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

/* Down */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    height: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    background-position: center 2px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment:hover {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment:active {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

/* Left */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-position: 3px 3px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement:hover {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement:active {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");
}

/* Right */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-position: 3px 3px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment:hover {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment:active {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
}
```

Comment: A newer version an better is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940522/how-do-i-switch-to-chromes-dark-scrollbar-like-github-does

Comment: Your SVG coding on the scroller triangles helped me on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72511916/105539).

Comment: It looks like `-webkit-scrollbar-button` is no longer supported in Chrome? I'm on a Mac and it's not showing at least

Answer (score 6):

Here's a light version.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#eee;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #8f8e8e;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

/* Buttons */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: block;
    background-size: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    height: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    background-position: center 4px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(73, 73, 73)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:active {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

/* Down */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    height: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    background-position: center 2px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(73, 73, 73)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment:hover {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment:active {
    background-image
```

Comment: how about horizontal arrows

Comment: copy the vertical and just change it to horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more awesome design [Codepen](https://codepen.io/khushwantk/pen/PomByxo)

Used Triangle SVG coverted to [data URI](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/image-to-datauri.html)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-position: center 4px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg 
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(121, 
  255, 108)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add custom scroll arrows in macOS. Initially, I felt that `::-webkit-scrollbar-button` was not working for Mac, but after some editing and fixing CSS, it seems to work for me (both Mac and Windows). Here is an example of the code:

```
  /* width */
 .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 16px;
  };

  /* Track */
  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  };

  /* Handle */
  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background: #C7C7C7;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:hover {
    background: #888;
  }

  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: block;
    background-color: #0099FE;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
  }

  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
    width: 22px;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(256, 256, 256)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");
  }

  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:increment {
    display: none;
  }

  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:decrement {
    display: none;
  }

  .scroll-d3-div::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment {
    width: 22px;
    background-position:center right;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(256, 256, 256)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
  }
```

[Here is how my horizontal scroll bar looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QwXw.png)

Note: `scroll-d3-div` this class name is given to div with the overflow property.

You can also refer to the links below, which were helpful for me in driving this solution.
[https://www.webmound.com/create-custom-scrollbars-css-ultimate-guide/#:~:text=To%20style%20arrow%20buttons%20in,with%20%3Ahorizontal%20pseudo%2Dclass](https://www.webmound.com/create-custom-scrollbars-css-ultimate-guide/#:%7E:text=To%20style%20arrow%20buttons%20in,with%20%3Ahorizontal%20pseudo%2Dclass).

https://blog.shahednasser.com/how-to-style-a-scrollbar-with-css/#webkit-scrollbar-button