# i want to Apply Border-Radius To Scrollbars with CSS

Tags: scroll, radius

I have a div with this scroll [see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9aFP.png)

but i want this type of scroll for my div [see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jti9E.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the below URL
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all web browsers react the same way, but you can try this:

```css
<style>
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000; 
}
</style>
```

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_scrollbar2

Comment: but the arrows are hidden when I apply this solution.

Comment: You can also look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576815/how-to-add-arrows-with-webkit-scrollbar-button