# How to custom scroll bar with default arrow in css

Tags: css

I want to customize the width and height of scrollbar but with default arrow

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
 
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
```

}

I didnt get default arrow. can anybody suggest here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add arrows with -webkit-scrollbar-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576815/how-to-add-arrows-with-webkit-scrollbar-button)

Comment: @Sfili_81 default arrow is not coming

Answer (score 2):

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0.05em solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Buttons */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 13px;
  width: 16px;
}


/* Up */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
}
/* Left */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement {
  border-width: 8px 0 8px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
}


/* Down */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-color: #555555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
  border-color: #777777 transparent transparent transparent;
}
/* Right */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment {
  border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}



/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:black;height:300px;width:600px;padding:8px;font-size:22px;overflow-y:scroll;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus
  ornare. Risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Mattis
  pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non. Lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Id aliquet risus
  feugiat in. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales
  neque sodales. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique. Euismod lacinia at quis risus
  sed. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero.
</div>
```

> You have to use

- `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` for thumb holder
- `::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button`,`:vertical:decrement`,`:vertical:increment`,`:horizontal:decrement`,`:horizontal:increment`, for buttons

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** The -webkit-scrollbar is not supported in Firefox or in Edge, prior to version 79. check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar) and [MDN CSS Scrollbars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars)

for more ways to create arrows : [How to add arrows with -webkit-scrollbar-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576815/how-to-add-arrows-with-webkit-scrollbar-button)

```css
/* width */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
}


/* Handle on hover */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
}


/* Handle on active*/

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}


/* Buttons */

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  display: block;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Up */

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
  height: 12px;
  width: 16px;
  background-position: center 4px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:active {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}


/* Down */

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
  height: 12px;
  width: 16px;
  background-position: center 2px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment:active {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}


/* Left */

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-position: 3px 3px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement:active {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='0,50 50,100 50,0'/></svg>");
}


/* Right */

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-position: 3px 3px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(96, 96, 96)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(112, 112, 112)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment:active {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='rgb(128, 128, 128)'><polygon points='0,0 0,100 50,50'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<p></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
```

---

**res**
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: his question is about triangle arrow, this answer don't have arrows

Comment: can u check the edit